# Shiny App Failed to Start - Cannot Locate File in Directory, but it is in Directory

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following shiny app that gives me exit error 1 message

```
require(tidyverse)
library(htmltools)
require(DT)

load("plate_disciple.Rdata")
load("batted_ball_data.Rdata")
load("hitting_table.Rdata")
load("pitcher_stats_fin.RData")
load("pitcher_stuff.RData")
load("defense.RData") 
load("catchers.RData") 


ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage(
    title = "X",
    tabPanel("Batter Stats", 
             h2("Batter Statistics"),
             DTOutput("table1")),
    tabPanel("Batted Ball Data", 
             h2("Batted Ball Statistics"),
             DTOutput("table2")),
    tabPanel("Plate Discipline", 
             h2("Plate Discipline Statistics"),
             DTOutput("table3")),
    tabPanel("Pitcher Stats",
             h2("Pitcher Stats"),
             DTOutput("table4")),
    tabPanel("Pitcher Stuff",
             h2("Pitcher Stuff"),
             DTOutput("table5")),
    tabPanel("Defense",
             h2("Defense"),
             DTOutput("table6")),
    tabPanel("Catching Defense",
             h2("Catching Defense"),
             DTOutput("table7")),
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table1 <- renderDT({
    datatable(hitting_table, 
              options = list(pageLength = 100), 
              class = 'cell-border stripe', 
              rownames = FALSE) %>%
      formatStyle(columns = c("OPS", "xOPS"), 
                  fontWeight = "bold",
                  backgroundColor = "#003366",
                  color = "white") %>% 
      formatStyle(columns = c("K%", "BB%"), 
                  fontWeight = "bold",
                  backgroundColor = "#CC0033",
                  color = "white")
  })
  
  output$table2 <- renderDT({
    datatable(batted_ball_data, 
              options = list(pageLength = 100), 
              class = 'cell-border stripe', 
              rownames = FALSE) %>%
      formatStyle(columns = c("EV", "90thEV"), 
                  fontWeight = "bold",
                  backgroundColor = "#003366",
                  color = "white") %>% 
      formatStyle(columns = c("BRL%", "HHLA"), 
                  fontWeight = "bold",
                  backgroundColor = "#CC0033",
                  color = "white")
  })
  
  output$table3 <- renderDT({
    datatable(plate_discipline, 
              options = list(pageLength = 100), 
              class = 'cell-border stripe', 
              rownames = FALSE) %>%
      formatStyle(columns = c("Whiff%", "Chase%"), 
                  fontWeight = "bold",
                  backgroundColor = "#003366",
                  color = "white") %>% 
      formatStyle(columns = c("K%", "BB%"), 
                  fontWeight = "bold",
                  backgroundColor = "#CC0033",
                  color = "white")
  })
  output$table4 <- renderDT({
    datatable(pitcher_stats_fin, 
              options = list(pageLength = 100), 
              class = 'cell-border stripe', 
              rownames = FALSE) %>%
      formatStyle(columns = c("ERA", "xERA"), 
                  fontWeight = "bold",
                  backgroundColor = "#003366",
                  color = "white") %>% 
      formatStyle(columns = c("K%", "BB%"), 
                  fontWeight = "bold",
                  backgroundColor = "#CC0033",
                  color = "white")
  })
  output$table5 <- renderDT({
    datatable(pitcher_stuff, 
              options = list(pageLength = 100), 
              class = 'cell-border stripe', 
              rownames = FALSE) %>%
      formatStyle(columns = c("Velo", "IVB", "HB", "Ext"), 
                  fontWeight = "bold",
                  backgroundColor = "#003366",
                  color = "white") %>% 
      formatStyle(columns = c("Whiff%", "Chase%"), 
                  fontWeight = "bold",
                  backgroundColor = "#CC0033",
                  color = "white")
  })
  output$table6 <- renderDT({
    datatable(defense, 
              options = list(pageLength = 100), 
              class = 'cell-border stripe', 
              rownames = FALSE) %>%
      formatStyle(columns = c("FieldPct"), 
                  fontWeight = "bold",
                  backgroundColor = "#003366",
                  color = "white") %>% 
      formatStyle(columns = c("OAA", "RunsSaved"), 
                  fontWeight = "bold",
                  backgroundColor = "#CC0033",
                  color = "white")
  })
  
  output$table7 <- renderDT({
    datatable(catchers_fin, 
              options = list(pageLength = 100), 
              class = 'cell-border stripe', 
              rownames = FALSE) %>%
      formatStyle(columns = c("CSAA"), 
                  fontWeight = "bold",
                  backgroundColor = "#003366",
                  color = "white") %>% 
      formatStyle(columns = c("WP", "PB", "Pop2B"), 
                  fontWeight = "bold",
                  backgroundColor = "#CC0033",
                  color = "white")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

My RData are located in the same folder as my app.r and they are compressed. In the logs it only does not load defense, (or at least gets there and then quits).
[image]

here is where all my files are loaded. Shiny is giving me exit error 1 with the log

```
2023-08-06T03:33:36.905333+00:00 shinyapps[9561207]:   cannot open compressed file 'defense.RData', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
2023-08-06T03:33:36.919313+00:00 shinyapps[9561207]: Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection
2023-08-06T03:33:36.919340+00:00 shinyapps[9561207]: Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
2023-08-06T03:33:36.919345+00:00 shinyapps[9561207]: Execution halted
2023-08-06T03:33:36.919348+00:00 shinyapps[9561207]: Shiny application exiting .
```

Comment: Are you trying to publish from windows server? or Linux based server? or Jenkins?.  You can try `load("./abc.Rdata")`  test on a small app which requires loading only one data set.